# gcc compile confuse in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

In my Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, I wrote a hello.c as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
  printf("Hello World!");
  return 0;
}
```

and then compiled with 
 
`> gcc hello.c`

which result in

`cat: /home/linky/workspace/repo/repository/build-tool3: No such file or directory
/tmp/ccA62XPs.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Then I typed 
 
`> which gcc`

`/usr/bin/gcc`

At first, I removed gcc from my system, and then reinstall it, but it didn't work. I am very confused about it. Please help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: usually it means you've got unresolved symbols, which is very confusing, because the program you're trying to compile is extremely simple; do you have libc-dev installed?

Comment: Please do : cd [folder with hello.c]/` ... like `cd /home/linky/tmp/ && gcc hello.c -o hello` .... Prerequisites : `apt install g++` ... I.e. with g++ also comes the packages that make gcc work fully. ( `libc6-dev,  linux-libc-dev` )

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get install g++` or `sudo apt-get install libc-dev` or `libc6-dev ` or `sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev`, shell shows that the lib is already the newest.